# Debugging No Free Units (LUNGET) from RasterToASCII_conversion() in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, esri-ascii-raster

I am converting approximately 20 years of satellite data to ASCII format (.asc) using ArcPy and rather than threading it, I chose to run four instances of the script in four different cmd windows. The code (slightly simplified) is as follows:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

years = range(1991, 2010, 4)
for year in years:
    for img in os.listdir("E:/tifs/{}".format(year)):
        if img[-3:] == "tif":
            output = "{}asc".format(img[:-3])
            print output
            arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion("E:/tifs/{}/{}".format(year, img), "E:/ascii/{}/{}".format(year, output)
```

I have four of these running, with the start of the years range increased by 1 for each script copy. After going through about a year of the data, the script stops with a cryptic message of `No free units (LUNGET)`, without any stacktrace:

[image: Screenshot]

This message does not turn up anywhere on ESRI help forums, stackoverflow, python forums, etc. The code runs fine without multiple instances of it running.

Comment: The LUN module was used to allocate file handles.  The error message indicates the OS does not have any free file handles (it is considered a fatal error).  You may have an issue with open files, which need explicit `del` closure.

Comment: Interesting. I'll see if I can contact ESRI since all file operations are in the closed source Arcpy modules, and I have no way of closing the files without access to the source.

Answer (score 3):

If this only shows up when running four instances of the script in four different cmd windows, then it would seem that a workaround might be to never run more than three instances of the script in three different cmd windows.