# How to set del or access environment vars / ArcPy Error "No Free Units (LUNGET)"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

This concerns the same error as [Debugging No Free Units (LUNGET) from RasterToASCII_conversion() in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/201846/187892).

Would anyone know how or where ArcPy is setting these directory paths below?  After exactly 12 iterations of TopoToRaster it stops with the Error "No Free Units (LUNGET)".   The below is output to the terminal, whether it completes successfully or throws this error.

```
*** Open files ***

Type Unit Acc Mem Count File
---- ---- --- --- ----- ----

 AF   43  rw   n   1    d:\usr\appdata\local\temp\sha1635       
 AF   44  rw   n   1    d:\usr\appdata\local\temp\sha1643       
 AF   45  rw   n   1    d:\usr\appdata\local\temp\sha1615       
 AF   46  rw   n   1    d:\usr\appdata\local\temp\sha1621       
 AF   47  rw   n   1    d:\usr\appdata\local\temp\sha1627
```

For each separate iteration I create and set a new scratch workspace with `arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace` and default workspace with `arcpy.env.workspace` and set `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1`.  But I am not setting these paths below and I don't know how to change them in the environment settings, or capture their paths to delete their contents.

OS is Windows 10 and I am using ArcPy in VSCode via ArcGIS Pro v2.8.

Comment: Following the link you had provided and reading it, it seems to me an OS resource issue. If this your attempt to parallelize your processing then have you tried the `multiprocessing` module? There are many Q&A on this and other forums about using that.

Comment: LUN errors are low-level file handling issues. Each process has a maximum number of permitted file handles. Running multiple I/O-intensive tasks in the same process could exceed the operating system limit.

Comment: @Vince would you know where I can find out more about this "LUN" error? I have trawled through the ArcPy code I haven't been able to trace it.  I can't find anything else online anywhere except that other question in this forum.  I don't think it is an OS limit, I think it must be an ESRI/Arcpy restriction.

Comment: @Hornbydd thank you I will look into the multiprocessing module.  It's a bit of a pain to only process 11 each time.

Comment: LUNSYS is documented in my Arc/Info 4.0 FORTRAN programmers' manuals (copyright 1987). It was of course rewritten with 'C' in the 90s. You won't find ArcPy references to it, since the ArcPy bridge is C++, on top of ArcObjects, and LUNSYS is 5-7 levels of architecture below that. Back when, applications couldn't access more than 6-10 file handles, so LUNSYS juggled the file handles so 12-20 files could be "open" at once. Now, since the limit is so much higher, the juggling code has likely been removed. If LUNGET can't allocate a file handle, it's probably due to an OS limit being exceeded.

Comment: Super helpful information @Vince.  I see what you're saying, I have a hunch that it is related to the environment.  If TopoToRaster is generating data over multiple iterations before producing the final raster and storing that somewhere other than the scratch and default workspaces set by myself/the user, then what you're saying about LUNSYS juggling the files makes sense.